# Why does np.argmax(None) return 0 and not throw an Exception?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, numpy, argmax

According to [Numpy's argmax documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html), the first argument we pass to `np.argmax` must be an array.

If the array is an empty list, we get a `ValueError Exception`:

```
import numpy as np
print(np.argmax([]))
```

> ValueError: attempt to get argmax of an empty sequence

However, if we pass `None` as the first argument to `np.argmax`, we get `0` as the output.

```
import numpy as np
print(np.argmax(None))
```

> 0

I find it odd that when it is passed an array (albeit empty but an array nonetheless) to `np.argmax` we get an Exception but when it is passed **NOT** an array (`None`) the program runs without error.

---

My questions:

1. Why does it not return an Exception since `None` is not an array?
2. Why does it return 0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input of `numpy.argmax` is **not** required to be an array - you're misreading the docs. The input is an *array-like*, which turns out to barely constrain the input at all. Almost anything is an array-like, including `None`, which is considered a 0-dimensional array-like of `object` dtype. Rather than constraining the input, "array-like" really describes how the input will be interpreted - if a parameter is documented as an array-like, NumPy will try to treat it as an array, usually with the equivalent of an `asarray` call.

If you don't pass an `axis`, argmax treats the input as flattened, so your call is equivalent to `numpy.argmax(numpy.array([None]))`. `None` isn't comparable, but `numpy` doesn't know that, because it has nothing to compare `None` to - there's only one input element, and that one input element is considered the max by default. `argmax` returns `0`, the index of the only element in the flattened input.

Comment: I was not aware of the "array-like" definition, thanks! Can you expand (or post a source) on this statement ``...which is considered a 0-dimensional array-like of object dtype``? I would like to read more about it.

Comment: @ihavenoidea: Try calling `asarray` on `None`, and you'll get a 0-dimensional array with `object` dtype.